# Enumerate JSON return

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, loops, enumerate

How do you enumerate a JSON return? The goal is to get a total count variable to add to my print statment...

I have

```
for i in services_js["reports"]:
            print " Service Name: " + i["instances"]["serviceName"]
```

and have tried:

```
for i in enumerate(services_js["reports"]):
            print " Service Name: " + i["instances"]["serviceName"]
```

but get:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Depends a lot on the structure of `services_js`. Care to show us an example?

Comment: I can't unfortunately my loop works...when I tried doing this with a counter it goes 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3... because `services_js` is a list of URLS `services_js = json.loads(services_open.read())`

Comment: If `services_js` is a list, then `services_js["reports"]` won't work, because you can't index a list with a string.

Comment: Dictionary*...it does work

Comment: Ok. If `i["instances"]` is a tuple, then `i["instances"]["serviceName"]` won't work, because you can't index a tuple with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT how `enumerate` works:

```
for i in enumerate(services_js["reports"]):
    print " Service Name: " + i["instances"]["serviceName"]
```

It works like this:

```
animals = ['rat', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog']
for i, animal in enumerate(animals, start=1):
    print('# {}: {}'.format(i, animal))
```

Notice how [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple, (`i` and `animal`) *not* just the count?

You may have other issues (in your JSON) but that part might be throwing you off.

The error you are seeing is because `i` is actually the tuple `(0, some_json)` and then you're trying to do `i['instance']`, so it's saying you can't use a string as an index to a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure without seeing the structure of the JSON, but going by the key names, you probably want

```
count = 0
for report in services_js["reports"]:
    for instance in report["instances"]:
        count += 1
        print "Service Name: " + instance["serviceName"]
print "there were {} total instances".format(count)
```

Comment: still get `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the `print` statment

Comment: Then I guessed the structure of your JSON incorrectly, and can do nothing more to help at this time. Sorry.